# Create a Dynamic Menu Link

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How to call either

```
RenderAction or Partial
```

I have try the following two ways

```
@Html.RenderAction("Link", Moorestown.Models.FooterMenu);
@Html.RenderPartial("Link", Moorestown.Models.FooterMenu);
```

This is located in my shared view but i am trying to call the partial of footer link so i can have a dynamic menu.

The error is `Moorestown.Models.FooterMenu is a type which is not valid in the following context`.

Here how my FooterMenu controller action looks like

```
 public PartialViewResult Link()
 {
   return PartialView(db.FooterMenus.ToList());
 }
```

I also have a partial view but has nothing in it for now, because i can't even call it corrctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
@Html.RenderAction("Link", Moorestown.Models.FooterMenu);
```

To

```
@Html.RenderAction("Link", "FooterMenu");
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing the object and NOT the type in your `RenderAction` or `RenderPartial` methods.

Comment: what do you mean by object, this is a list of all the footermenu, i am new to asp.net

Comment: @Jseb, Will be glad to help you. Moorestown.Models.FooterMenu is actually the Type; however the object have been already passed by the controller to your view. You will get a handle of your object using keyword **Model** in your view. From there you would be able to access all the properties/objects that you have injected to this view through your controller.

Comment: I have seen that you can do something like this @{ Html.RenderAction("Items", new { requestId = Model.Id }); }. However again I want a list like an index of all FooterMenu that is define in my index

Comment: Okay. Are you looking for something like **Paging**?

Answer (score 0):

You can call partial view with this

> @Html.Partial("_DistrictDetailGrid", Model)

**"_DistrictDetailGrid"** is a partial view name.